# AWS|Traffic mirroring by using iptables

Tags: iptables, mirroring

I am trying to achieve Network Traffic Mirroring with iptables,In my scenario, i am mirroring the traffic on Server 1 to Server 2's IP address. Apparently configurations are straight foreword as follow

```
Server 1
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t mangle -I POSTROUTING -j TEE --gateway 172.31.34.228 (Server 2 IP)
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -j TEE --gateway 172.31.34.228
```

But when i run tcpdump on Server 2's interface(172.31.34.228), it is not showing any results. 
Both servers are on AWS and under same subnet, OS is AWS latest IAM,

```
[root@ip-172-31-37-29 ~]# iptables --version
iptables v1.4.21
```

Kernel Modules

```
[root@ip-172-31-37-29 ~]# ls /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/net/netfilter/
ipset                       nf_log_common.ko        nf_tables_inet.ko    nft_objref.ko       xt_cluster.ko      xt_hashlimit.ko  xt_nat.ko       xt_sctp.ko
ipvs                        nf_log_netdev.ko        nf_tables.ko         nft_queue.ko        xt_comment.ko      xt_helper.ko     xt_NETMAP.ko    xt_SECMARK.ko
nf_conntrack_amanda.ko      nf_nat_amanda.ko        nf_tables_netdev.ko  nft_redir.ko        xt_connbytes.ko    xt_hl.ko         xt_nfacct.ko    xt_set.ko
nf_conntrack_broadcast.ko   nf_nat_ftp.ko           nft_compat.ko        nft_reject_inet.ko  xt_connlabel.ko    xt_HL.ko         xt_NFLOG.ko     xt_socket.ko
nf_conntrack_ftp.ko         nf_nat_irc.ko           nft_counter.ko       nft_reject.ko       xt_connlimit.ko    xt_HMARK.ko      xt_NFQUEUE.ko   xt_state.ko
nf_conntrack_h323.ko        nf_nat.ko               nft_ct.ko            nft_rt.ko           xt_connmark.ko     xt_IDLETIMER.ko  xt_osf.ko       xt_statistic.ko
nf_conntrack_irc.ko         nf_nat_redirect.ko      nft_exthdr.ko        nft_set_bitmap.ko   xt_CONNSECMARK.ko  xt_ipcomp.ko     xt_owner.ko     xt_string.ko
nf_conntrack.ko             nf_nat_sip.ko           nft_fib_inet.ko      nft_set_hash.ko     xt_conntrack.ko    xt_iprange.ko    xt_physdev.ko   xt_tcpmss.ko
nf_conntrack_netbios_ns.ko  nf_nat_tftp.ko          nft_fib.ko           nft_set_rbtree.ko   xt_cpu.ko          xt_ipvs.ko       xt_pkttype.ko   xt_TCPMSS.ko
nf_conntrack_netlink.ko     nfnetlink_acct.ko       nft_fib_netdev.ko    x_tables.ko         xt_CT.ko           xt_l2tp.ko       xt_policy.ko    xt_TCPOPTSTRIP.ko
nf_conntrack_pptp.ko        nfnetlink_cthelper.ko   nft_hash.ko          xt_addrtype.ko      xt_dccp.ko         xt_length.ko     xt_quota.ko     xt_tcpudp.ko
nf_conntrack_proto_gre.ko   nfnetlink_cttimeout.ko  nft_limit.ko         xt_AUDIT.ko         xt_devgroup.ko     xt_limit.ko      xt_rateest.ko   xt_TEE.ko
nf_conntrack_sane.ko        nfnetlink.ko            nft_log.ko           xt_bpf.ko           xt_dscp.ko         xt_LOG.ko        xt_RATEEST.ko   xt_time.ko
nf_conntrack_sip.ko         nfnetlink_log.ko        nft_masq.ko          xt_cgroup.ko        xt_DSCP.ko         xt_mac.ko        xt_realm.ko     xt_TPROXY.ko
nf_conntrack_snmp.ko        nfnetlink_queue.ko      nft_meta.ko          xt_CHECKSUM.ko      xt_ecn.ko          xt_mark.ko       xt_recent.ko    xt_TRACE.ko
nf_conntrack_tftp.ko        nf_synproxy_core.ko     nft_nat.ko           xt_CLASSIFY.ko      xt_esp.ko          xt_multiport.ko  xt_REDIRECT.ko  xt_u32.ko

[root@ip-172-31-37-29 ~]# rpm -ql kernel | grep xt_TEE
/lib/modules/4.14.62-70.117.amzn2.x86_64/kernel/net/netfilter/xt_TEE.ko
/lib/modules/4.14.70-72.55.amzn2.x86_64/kernel/net/netfilter/xt_TEE.ko
```

I am really stuck, and any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am stuck with the same issue..

Comment: are you using AWS Traffic Mirroring? If yes, did you open port [UDP port 4789](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/mirroring/traffic-mirroring-targets.html) so that mirrored traffic can be accepted at the target?

Answer (score 0):

According to [SO](https://serverfault.com/questions/236503/need-to-duplicate-udp-packets-to-multiple-destinations-via-iptables) thread target must be in same network as your computer. https://code.google.com/archive/p/port-mirroring/ is hinted to be alternative way of achieving your goal but it seems to be openwrt specific.